# b43 wireless driver error

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, broadcom

I just installed Arch, and I noticed that my wifi range is very poor. I have to be about 10 feet away from the router for it to work. I also noticed that when I boot, I get this message:

> Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param `allhwsupport=0`. Try `b43.allhwsupport=1`

I am completely new to Linux and I have no idea what this means. I would assume that I would re-install or update my drivers, but I have no idea how to do that. I looked for about 3 hours on the Arch wiki, but no where on there does it say how to actually update the drivers. It's as if it's assumed that I know how to do it. I am using a Broadcom chip, and I would like to know if it's a simple problem, or how I can update or reinstall the drivers via the terminal. Is it done with pacman? I have no idea.

Comment: hit the same on debian testing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that support for that particular chip or firmware version is still not very stable.

The message is telling you to [pass an option to the `b43` kernel module](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Setting_module_options) to activate support for your chip version. This may improve things or not. To do so, create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf` containing the lines

```
# Activate experimental support for some hardware revisions
options b43 allhwsupport=1
```

To make the settings come into effect, turn off networking and unload then reload the module with the commands

```
rmmod b43
modprobe b43
```

Run these commands as root, i.e. with `su` or `sudo`.

Aside: Arch is a distribution for people who like a hands-on approach. If you prefer things to be done automatically, it may not be the best distribution for you.

Comment: i wish i had seen this before switching back to ubuntu

Comment: well, I have the same issue on ubuntu

Comment: @Gilles : Will this solution work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @crisron Yes, the resolution is independent of the distribution. If you find that a piece of hardware requires an option, you might submit a bug report against the installer to request that this option is added automatically.

Comment: in debian testing must install firmware-b43-installer package after created config file.